# R - Cannot correctly display grayscale image from binary file

Tags: r, image, binaryfiles

I want to display a grayscale image stored as a binary file. I tried the image and RasterImage functions, but the output looks of less quality than the original's. Here is an example of my code:

```
finfo=file.info("image_file")

toread= file("image_file","rb")

image_data = readBin(toread, integer(), size=1, n = finfo$size, endian="little")

img_m<-matrix(image_data,nrow=480,ncol=640)

image(data_m,axes=FALSE,col=grey(seq(0,1,length=256)))
```

The ouput of the code above looks like this:

[image]

Howerver, the original image looks like this:

[image]

I tried the same with Python, using the Image.frombytes function and it displays the image correctly. I haven't been able to do the same with R.

UPDATE: I set the first 150,000 pixels to 0 just to see if it would affect correctly the display and instead of black pixels I got gray pixels. Here is the image:

[image]

Does anybody know the right function to display it correctly, or what is missing in my code to get the right image?

I appreciate any insight on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two main things to solve this. The first is that using `integer()` as the `what` parameter in the `readBin()` causes the binary file to be read as a vector of signed integers. Thus, the obtained vector contained negative values, which affected the grayscale. To solve this, I used `raw()` as the `what` argument and then converted the vector to integer with `as.integer()`.

The second change is that I used the `rasterImage()` function instead of the `image()` function to display the image, since the former function outputs an image with higher contrast than the original.